# How to convert hex to double in iphone

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c

I have this code in Java:

```
   String pr = "4173df24c969ff63"
   long prLongBits = Long.valueOf(pr, HEX_BASE).longValue();
   prDoubleValue = Double.longBitsToDouble(prLongBits);
```

the result of: prDoubleValue = 2.083694058837832E7

How would i convert this in Objective C?? 
i tried to convert from hex to long and then long to double, but no proper result.

BR,

Suppi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try something like the following:

```
// Read the hex string into a 64-bit integer
unsigned long long doubleBits;
double result;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"4173df24c969ff63"];
if ([scanner scanHexLongLong:&doubleBits]) {
    memcpy(&result, &doubleBits, sizeof(result)l
}
```

I haven't tried it out but the basic idea should be approximately right. You want to convert the hex string to a bunch of bytes stored in a numeric data type of an appropriate size. Once that bit pattern is in memory we copy it into the memory assigned to a double.

This assumes that the string representation used to create the hex string used the same byte ordering as the one where your code is running.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat ambiguous, but I believe that you want to interpret the string as the encoding of a `double`.  Here's one way to do that:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double interpretAsDouble(const char *string) {
    // convert the string to a 64-bit int ...
    uint64_t encoding;
    sscanf(string, "%"SCNx64, &encoding);
    // ... then interpret that 64-bit int as the encoding of a double.
    double value;
    memcpy(&value, &encoding, sizeof value);
    return value;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%g\n", interpretAsDouble("4173df24c969ff63"));
    return 0;
}
```